# Clarifying AWS tutorial for User identification - variables change

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Doing this tutorial:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html
I found the following prompt:

To use this identity provider, you have to pass it into CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider. Here's an example:

```
DeveloperAuthenticationProvider developerProvider = new DeveloperAuthenticationProvider( null, "IDENTITYPOOLID", context, Regions.USEAST1);
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider( context, developerProvider, Regions.USEAST1);
```

Should I place it in the class mentioned above it or it goes to the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put that code wherever you instantiate the credentials provider (which should ideally be a singleton). As far as region, can you try Regions.US_EAST_1 instead of Regions.USEAST1?

The Cognito [sample app](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo) has an example implementation, if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention in `DeveloperAuthenticationProvider` class and not the caching provider.

Comment: Thanks, but then, why there is error with "conten" even when I import import android.content.Context; and Regions.US_EAST is not recognized?

Comment: you have to use region endpoint as "USEast1" and not "US_East" that is why you get that error

Comment: USEAST1 and not EAST1